# Export data from Elasticsearch to CSV using Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, export-to-csv

How can I export data from Elasticsearch to CSV using Logstash? I need to include only specific columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install 2 [plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/working-with-plugins.html): [elasticsearch input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) and [csv output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-csv.html).
Then create [a configuration file](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/config-examples.html). Here is [a good example for this particular case](https://gist.github.com/sergey-alekseev/b3edf7702a86b72c05ed8e65fb257cd0).

You are ready to go now, just run:
`bin/logstash -f /path/to/logstash-es-to-csv-example.conf`

And check `export.csv` file specified in `output -> csv -> path`.

Answer (score 2):

**Important note:**
There is a known bug in csv output plugin when working with Logstash 5.x. The plugin generates a string of `%{host} %{message}%{host} %{message}%{host} %{message}`.
There's an open issue for it: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/issues/10

As a workaround you may:

- downgrade to Logstash 2.x until this gets resolved
- use the file output instead

  ```
  file {
      codec => line { format => "%{field1},%{field2}"}
      path => "/path/to/data_export.csv"
  }
  ```
- modify the plugin's code according to the github discussion...