# Logstash CSV output plugin

Tags: csv, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash to parse a file containing single line JSON data and output it in a CSV formatted file.  Instead of outputting the data as nice separated values it is giving me single line data using timestamp, host, and message fields. I found [this question](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/csv-output-is-not-working/71554) on the official Logstash forums however it had no responses. Has anyone else encountered this issue and know how to fix it or have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

### Output

Current output

```
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
2017-02-08T16:48:45.907Z %{host} %{message}
```

Desired output

```
timestamp, id, name
timestamp, id, name
timestamp, id, name
```

### Config

```
input {
    file {
        path => "input path"
        sincedb_path => "C:\Logstash\.sincedb*"
        start_position => "beginning"
        codec => "json"
        type => "type"
    }
}

filter {
    mutate {
        add_field => {"eventName" => "%{[event][eventName]}"}
        add_field => {"uniqueDeviceID" => "%{[event][deviceSegment][uniqueDeviceID]}"}
    }
    prune {
        whitelist_names => ["eventName", "uniqueDeviceID", "@timestamp"]
    }
}

output {
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
    csv {
        fields => ["uniqueDeviceID", "eventName", "@timestamp"]
        path => "output path"
    }
}
```

Comment: So the stdout rubydebug output looks correct while the csv output has this issue?

Comment: If you're using Logstash 5, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41681873/sending-slowlogs-to-csv-file/41688796#41688796

Comment: Logstash 5.x was my issue. I ended up finding a solution here https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/pull/11. The changes in the pull request made it work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug

[Export data from Elasticsearch to CSV using Logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007206/export-data-from-elasticsearch-to-csv-using-logstash)

https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-csv/issues/10