# Export Kibana to CSV

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, export, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

How do I export Kibana data to CSV?
All I could find was "Select Discover from the menu -> Click Share -> Click Export to CSV", but the last menu seems to lack the "Export to CSV" button. Am I doing something wrong?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfLPL.png)

**EDIT:**
The question refers to AWS Kibana which is different from the regular Kibana and the AWS version did not support export to CSV at the time. They may add it in the future, but do not plan on doing it soon (see accepted answer).

Comment: You should use Logstash for that. It's a duplicate question. See there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007206/export-data-from-elasticsearch-to-csv-using-logstash

Comment: @vanderkorn what about this method?  
https://reelyactive.github.io/diy/kibana-export-data-csv-file/  
is not supported anymore?

Comment: It uses Kibana for exporting. It should be working. But I've never used that method. Might it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34792146/export-to-csv-excel-from-kibana

Comment: @vanderkorn yeah, I saw that one too. It is 4 years old and I cannot find any way to export all of the data, only aggregates (sum, count, etc).  I wouldn't start a new thread if I didn't search this site first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your screenshot looks like it might be the AWS Kibana, which is a fork off of Elastic's Kibana and does not have export-to-CSV support. See https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=897857

I was looking for this today and found both your and the above posts. Replying to help those who might come behind me.  In my case, I just needed a little data and did an ugly cut-and-paste - did not come up with a mechanism to export CSV from AWS Kibana.

Comment: It seems like you are right. I didn't know that there are differences between Kibana and AWS Kibana at the time.